# Me.Close does not work

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm working with VB.net.
I’m having problems while I connect my application to my database today so I wanted to add an error handling to close the form.

The problem is that when I put `Me.close` in a form, this form still open. I used the `Form.Closing` event handler to verify that it was called, and then ran my application in step by step which showed that the event handler was called, but the application continues and the errors appears to the user.

Does anyone knows how to close a form properly without closing the application?

Comment: do you have several forms? maybe you could try to call it by its name instead of `Me`. Something like `Form1.Close()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've thought about that, but in the form i want to close, i use a try catch, and i wanted to put the Me.close in the catch. So i don't think it's possible to close it from another form at the right moment.

Comment: Do you exit from all code that is activated from the form that is closed? closing a form does not de-active code! You need to exit.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. I thought that Me.close would close the form and end the code but it doesn't. With an exit it works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Close` *will* close a form, but only if it has no more code to run.

That is, there are two conditions that need to be fulfilled for a form to close:

- `Close` must be called
- Any method still running must be left

I suspect that another method is still running code, for instance a loop or other code that causes the form to remain open.

Furthermore, the form will get re-opened automatically once you start accessing its members form elsewhere, due to an infuriating property of VB to auto-instantiate forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for what reason the form don't get closed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.FormClosing

   MsgBox(e.CloseReason.ToString)

End Sub
```

You can add to the Form_Closing event the following
The e.Cancel will close the open operation. But first check the reason.

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.FormClosing

  e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the CloseReason is UserClose. I changed a bit my programm and it seems that the form doesn't close but the objects that it contains aren't accessible any more because when i put the me.close, i have then an error when i'm trying to modify a Datagridview. The error is "Impossible to reach a deleted object.
Name of the object: ' DataGridView '." I hope i'm enough clear in my explanations.

Comment: The error clearly indicates, that the form is closed, but on some other place in your code, you are still accessing the objects in the form, see my comment above

Answer (score 1):

Technically the form is closed but not disposed, which means you can still reach the object but all controls in it are no longer reachable.

So you will have to call dispose from somewhere to get rid of it completely.