# Visual Studio Automated UI Test Hangs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, coded-ui-tests, infragistics

Firstly I am using VS2013 Winforms .net 4.0.

After excluding all other possibilities (from my set of possibilities) the culprit appears to be Me.close() in one specific form. After the me.close() method executes the coded-ui-test application seems to freeze and does not give any feedback about the buttons i am pressing or text i am entering. When I ask it to generate the code it goes as long as 1 hour before I decide to give up and kill the process. When I try the same test without the me.close it works as expected. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this bug in the automated ui testing? If not can you suggest any alternatives please?

Edit: This does not happen when I simply press the forms 'X' button in the top right. This is very strange.

Edit2: I have tried this in a fresh project. It is indeed me.close that causes the coded ui test application to 'freeze' such that I cannot generate the automated code and I will end up stuck at the 'please wait' loading bar.

Edit3: It appears to be specific to calling me.close in an infragistics click handler of a ultrabutton. Wow, here is example.

Designer

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class closemepls
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.UltraButton1 = New Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'UltraButton1
    '
    Me.UltraButton1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(45, 47)
    Me.UltraButton1.Name = "UltraButton1"
    Me.UltraButton1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(232, 157)
    Me.UltraButton1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.UltraButton1.Text = "UltraButton1"
    '
    'closemepls
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.UltraButton1)
    Me.Name = "closemepls"
    Me.Text = "closemepls"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
Friend WithEvents UltraButton1 As Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton
End Class
```

Code

```
Public Class closemepls

Private Sub UltraButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UltraButton1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

If I call closemepls.showdialog() and click the button the coded ui test application freezes! Infragistics FTW.

This is the result, it does not complete even after 1 hour.

[image: This is the hanging application I am talking about]

Comment: How about minimal example to reproduce?

Comment: @Evk im not sure is SO alerts you on edit but I added an example, however it requires a 3rd party control to run.

Comment: Where is the documentation on the `close` method. My quick web search finds http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton_members.html about the `ultrabutton` class, but there is no `close` on that page. Also, what level of support does Infragistics claim for Coded UI?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Me.close is a .NET method on the form not infragistics.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like that in WPF before.

Here's how I found it: Comment everything out then find the code that causes the problem by adding blocks back one by one.

It's something that is binded (anything though, not data and more than likely a control) not being released.

Comment: I commented out nearly all the code. All that is left is the default constructor and a button that calls me.close on click. It is defiently the me.close call that is causing the coded ui test app to freeze. This is so awful.

Comment: Try to use Me.Hide

Comment: That worked but that is not an ideal workaround. The code base I am working on is quite large and probably has code dependent upon the form closing. Thanks though i will try this out and see if it works for us.

Comment: Actually it does not work when the child form is a dialog even when using me.hide.

Comment: That can't be anything to do with the owner setting, can it? Try visibility.

Comment: I am not sure either. Ive checked every property on the form object and the  designer and I cannot find the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried mixing CodedUI and VB much, but I was hoping this question may help you:

[Me.Close does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512511/me-close-does-not-work)

Alone, that doesn't mean much, right? But in conjunction with how CodedUI works it may provide a clue. Remember that when you're running a test you're technically initiating a UITesting.Playback, which is a process. You may want to add something to your TestCleanup method that makes sure all the processes are terminated, like so (Keep in mind that this is for a browser test):

```
/// <summary>
/// Closes the test browser and ends test playback
/// </summary>
[TestCleanup]//The decorator is what makes this a method a test cleanup
public void CleanTest()
{        
    if (Playback.IsInitialized) //This is the important part.
    {
        Playback.Cleanup();
    }
    if (browserWindow.Exists)
    {
        browserWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

This is just a shot in the dark and I may even be misunderstanding what you need, really but I'm assuming that in both your real and example areas you're closing the entire application? This may be a question for Infragistics at the end of the day. Good luck!

Comment: I added a picture to explain it better, I think you are thinking that I am hanging during a run of a ui unit test, but the app is the one that is hanging. I dont think [TestCleanup] tag can be used in the winform app right?

Comment: So, your app is not what's hanging. The CodedUI engine is what's hanging at the moment. You can only call TestCleanup methods during the execution of a CodedUI test, so I think you are correct in that my suggestion may not help you.

Let me know if this is correct: You have an winforms application, with infragistics controls. In the application's solution, you have a CodedUI project. Within that CodedUI project, you have a class where you have tests. When the tests do something that calls me.close, the CodedUI engine does not produce the code and map artifacts - instead VS freezes.

Comment: The application code and CodedUI project are in different solutions, I think it did not make a difference for me when they were in the same solution and here is why. In the test project In the default <TestMethod()> tagged method I hit ctrl+\ & ctrl + c to start the CodedUI Engine App (my picture). I then click the exe of the built application and open the child form via ultrabutton then hit the child ultrabutton to call me.close, then the coded ui engine app freezes and I cannot press the button which inserts the code from the engine into my CodedUITest project so that I can run it later.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I think we are saying the same thing different ways here. The problem lies in the CodedUI engine that generates the code for you.

Here's what I would try. In your codedUI solution, try to write a test by  hand that does what you're doing now. See if it works. You can use the generated code for other tests as a guide, but instead of defining objects in different classes just do them inline during the test. If you can't create the test by hand, you'll need to write a custom harness or get one from Infragistics.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same issue I've experienced when using `MTM`, on a few machines if they were running any form of capture for the resulting test. They where trying to save it to a illegal path(Found in Event Viewer). After performing a repair on `VS` thus `MTM` to was repaired and it worked for some machines. Others only seamed to be fixed when going to update 4.

But code wise I would suggest trying to click the close button on the form itself to see if you get a different behavior.

```
Dim closeButton = New WinButton(YourWindow);
closeButton.SearchProperties(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name) = "Close";
Mouse.Click(closeButton);
```